# How to set the size of an AutoCompleteTextView Result?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Does anybody know How to set the size of an AutoCompleteTextView Result ?

[image]

I try `android:textSize="12sp"` But it only modify the size of the text in the TextView, not in the result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way is to create your own xml file with a customized design, such as  "dropdown.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F3F5E1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

and in your code use this

```
AutoCompleteTextView etChoose= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etChoose);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChoose = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.dropdown, ChooseList);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add `android:dropDownHeight="size"` for `AutoCompleteTextView` in xml file.

Comment: The picture in the question shows a desire to change the individual item height.  Setting `dropDownHeight` changes the height of the entire dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                          (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourList) {

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(14);                             
        Typeface Type = getFont () ;  // custom method to get a font from "assets" folder
        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Type);               
        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(YourColor);                                             
        ((TextView) v) .setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        return v;
    }           
};

 YourAutoCompleteView.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming someone is facing the same issue now

Instead of using simple_spinner_item you can also use simple_spinner_dropdown_item to get better results as it will format the data as it would appear in a normal dropdown

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, subjects1);
```