# How to change text size of dropdown of autocomplete text view

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

There is a way to change text size of dropdown of autocomplete text view in android. In my process, I want to do programmatically. If there is some way, please teach me how to do. 
Thanks.

Comment: You have to implement your custom adapter with custom view.

Comment: @Misaki Yuki Check out  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539469/how-to-set-the-size-of-an-autocompletetextview-result)  question. It may help you...

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a method to increase the size of the drop-down:

Below is the **method** to do so.

```
setDropDownWidth(int width);
```

[image]

Comment: I think that tittle not is incorrect but say : How to change text size DropDow not setDropDownWidth .... is so easy read :(

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    AutoCompleteTextViewStyle autoAddItem = (AutoCompleteTextViewStyle) findViewById(R.id.autoAddItem); //Customized AutoCompleteTextView

    final List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    String[] from = { "txt"};
    int[] to = {R.id.txtItemName};

    SimpleAdapter shopItemAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), aList, R.layout.custom_auto_complete_drop_down, from, to); 
    //R.layout.custom_auto_complete_drop_down is the customized layout for dropdown item of your autocompletetextview
    //You can set text size on your XML layout
    autoAddItem.setAdapter(shopItemAdapter);
```

Comment: I think the requirement is to change the size dynamically.

Changing XML during runtime is the heavy operation, so better is to change it dynamically in java only.