# Why keyboard is overlap on the AutoCompleteTextView when inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple android layout and code, but the keyboard always overlap my `AutoCompleteTextView` when I click it.
Note : The AutoCompleteTextView when inside ScrollView.
Note : platform is 6.0.1

```
package com.example.jason_wu.search;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAtv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mAtv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.location_auto_complete);
        //issue 1
        //mAtv.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.search_input_focus));
        //issue 2
        mAtv.setHeight(300);
    }
}
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.jason_wu.search">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.jason_wu.search.Main2Activity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

Layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/location_auto_complete"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/location_auto_complete"
                android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="1dip"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:hint="@string/new_notification_location_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textUri"
                android:dropDownSelector="@color/location_bg_select"
                android:popupBackground="@color/location_bg_notselect"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:alpha="0.2"
                android:textColorHint="#999999"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/location_auto_complete" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

See [image: issue 2]

Comment: use adjust pan attribute in your activity tag in manifest

Comment: can you post the layout for the activity ?

Comment: @PankajNimgade, xml is update.

Comment: @VivekMishra, Sure, I am try below :

A."android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
B."android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, Kindly put the layout that we can check you have uploaded an image of that activity

Comment: @PankajNimgade, I am already upload layout.xml, please kindly help, many thanks.

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, hi, i have updated my answer, let me know if this is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard behavior is that scroll the view to close the bottom of text area.

Finally, we have to use `android:gravity="bottom"` attribute to solve UI issue, but we need to consider the UX, ex: Hint.

So, The solution is to listen `onClick()` and For keyboard issue, we have to use dynamic method to set the gravity.

Answer (score 3):

try this attribute to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

it should look something like this.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myexample.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/login_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" // well you can change the orientation if you want
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

the attribute you want to play with is this `windowSoftInputMode` try different values as you may require different output after certain time.

```
adjustPan
```

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

```
adjustResize
```

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

```
stateHidden
```

> The soft keyboard is hidden when the user chooses the activity — that is, when the user affirmatively navigates forward to the activity, rather than backs into it because of leaving another activity.

you can find more details on [activity-element documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Update

I have written something that might help you, layout is available on the [layout](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_test_layout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="activities.list.first.TestLayoutActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/TestLayoutActivity_autoCompleteTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                    android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <activity
        android:name="activities.list.first.TestLayoutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test_layout"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        />
```

> Code is on the [code](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/TestLayoutActivity.java)

```
    String[] list = {"match1", "match2", "match3",
            "match12", "match11", "match8", "match7", "match4",
            "match13", "match10", "match9", "match6", "match5",};

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.TestLayoutActivity_autoCompleteTextView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

Before
```

[image: Before]

```
After
```

[[image: after]]

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
But still happen even if add attribute in xml
"android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"

Comment: Kindly try... "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: thanks for reply, but still fail on 
"android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: I am so thank for you answer.
But I know the AutoCompleteTextView is normal work without ScrollView.
But issue is occurred if AutoCompleteTextView with ScrollView, So it's point, I am trying solved it.

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, Kindly post your layout with **ScrollView**, let me see what can I do

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I had upload the layout with Scrollview, please kindly help, so many thanks.

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, give me few minutes, let me check it I will try to fix it

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, I am using ScrollView now, it works in my code, Kindly check this layout https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_test_layout.xml and for the code... https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/TestLayoutActivity.java

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, Great! 
 thank you for accepting the answer :)

Comment: The issue still exist if you adjust the Text view height 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="800dp"
    android:text="New Text" />


And use below one method.

autoCompleteTextView.setHeight(300);
autoCompleteTextView.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.search_input_focus));
autoCompleteTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

So sad. I think it's layout issue, but still happen.

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, do you mean the height of the autoCompleteTextView or the popup which comes on that

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, your layout may change over period of time and if you are handling portrait/ landscape mode it would be best to let android system decide the height of popup of autoCompleteTextView

Comment: I mean you set other view height for scroll AutoCompleteTextView, and adjust autoCompleteTextView's  Height /  Background / BackgroundColor.

Note : I always use portrait mode to review it, So it's not relayout issue?

Comment: I am not sure about the height or what can i recommend. you should give this site a try for color.. http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Any height or color will trigger issue happen, maybe it's google issue ?

Comment: @Chun-ShenWu, you may be right, not everything is perfect or we don't know how to do it. what you can do is write a mail to google about the issue you are facing, either they will tell what to do or they will fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try limiting the dropdown items to show**

One way is you can Limit the dropdown items to show. But there's no such proper way of it to show number of maximumSuggestions option, But the trick you can apply is Get the height of one of the rows and multiply it (number of rows to show) times and use `setDropDownHeight()` to set its height.

There is a method [setDropDownHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownHeight%28int%29) of [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) class. You can see them and use.

If you are confused or not sure of height of suggestions items you can customize this. Have a look [how to set custom height.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539469/how-to-set-the-size-of-an-autocompletetextview-result)